# django testing with local settings

Tags: python, django

Python 2.7
Django 1.2

I am getting odd local_settings behavior when I am testing a Django app.  I have my `<project>/settings.py` set up like this:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
        ("Me", "me@me.com"),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS + (('Person1', 'person1@blah.com'),)

# ... rest of settings

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

and in `<project>/local_settings.py` I have:

```
DEBUG = True

MANAGERS = (
        ('Me', 'me@me.com'),
)
```

So, while working locally, the `MANAGERS` setting should be `(('Me', 'me@me.com'),)`, and `DEBUG` should be set to `True`.

However, in the tests for one of my apps, I am testing `settings.DEBUG` and getting `False`, but the `MANAGERS` setting is set correctly (it just has 'Me' in it).  Any ideas why this would happen?  Here are the relevant parts of the `<project>/<app>/tests.py` file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase

# ...
class MyTests(TestCase):
    def mytest(self):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            self.assertEqual(settings.MANAGERS, (('Me', 'me@me.com'),))
        else:
            self.assertEqual(settings.MANAGERS, (('Me', 'me@me.com'), ('Person1', 'person1@blah.com')))
```

The result is

```
AssertionError: (('Me', 'me@me.com'),) != (('Me', 'me@me.com'), ('Person1', 'person1@blah.com'))
```

So it looks like it is testing the `else` branch due to `settings.DEBUG` being set incorrectly, and then raising `AssertionError` since `settings.MANAGERS` is set correctly.

If I run `python manage.py shell` I get this:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DEBUG
True
>>> settings.MANAGERS
(('Me', 'me@me.com'),)
```

So they are set correctly there.

I know I can override settings manually in my tests, but I wanted to try to use `settings.DEBUG` so that the test would pass no matter whether it was being run locally or in production.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Unit test with different settings in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913549/how-to-unit-test-with-different-settings-in-django)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an intentional choice within Django:

> Regardless of the value of the DEBUG setting in your configuration file, all Django tests run with DEBUG=False. This is to ensure that the observed output of your code matches what will be seen in a production setting.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#other-test-conditions

Comment: This is NUTS. How are you supposed to debug your tests? What if you have emails only set when DEBUG is False?

Comment: @MagicLAMP You can use [override_settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) in that case

Answer (score 3):

Use `--settings` option when running tests

```
python manage.py test --settings=mysite.settings_local
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Django turns DEBUG to false no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I recall reading that you're not supposed to change settings values in any way at runtime, it causes problems.

Comment: The django documentation says not to do this:
`settings.BLAH = 'blah'` outside of a settings file but importing a file into a settings file is kosher