# How to mock django settings attribute used in another module?

Tags: python, mocking

Lets say module `a` code:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.BASE_URL # prints http://example.com
```

In `tests.py` I want to mock the `BASE_URL` to `http://localhost`

I have tried the following:

```
with mock.patch('django.conf.settings.BASE_URL', 'http://localhost'):
    pass

with mock.patch('a.settings.BASE_URL', 'http://localhost'):
    pass

from a import settings

with mock.patch.object(settings, 'BASE_URL', 'http://localhost'):
    pass

import a

with mock.patch.object(a.settings, 'BASE_URL', 'http://localhost'):
    pass
```

None of the above worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Unit test with different settings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913549/how-to-unit-test-with-different-settings-in-django)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to use context manager settings() built-in django.

```
with self.settings(BASE_URL='http://localhost'):
    # perform your test
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.settings

Answer (score 25):

You can also use the following decorator on your individual test functions or test class as a whole. For example:

```
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(BASE_URL='http://localhost')
def test_case()
    ...
```

Comment: Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings

Comment: To import this decorator in Django 3.0: `from django.test import override_settings`