# django change cache settings when testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-cache, django-redis

I'm using redis as my cache server. When a user created , the post_save signal will save his information in redis with `key="user_info_<userid>"`. However, when I run the unit test and create the user, the information will be overwritten. How can I prevent this. How can I change the cache storage when testing?

Comment: Every comments may be helpfull. Please leave your opinion, thankyou.

Comment: use code to disable you redis cache service before you test code

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913549/how-to-unit-test-with-different-settings-in-django)  may help you

Comment: Thank you Ykh. That is really helpful. I will test and discuss the solutions in that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Unit test with different settings in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913549/how-to-unit-test-with-different-settings-in-django)